# CLT concept regarding repeated samples

Tags: central-limit-theorem

From the  probability and statistics books, that i have studied,  my understanding of central limit theorem is as follows:

CLT is applicable in case of repeated samples i.e. when we take a single sample of n observations and then we repeat the same experiment a number Of times to generate a group of samples and each such sample is of size $n$. So if the sample means of each such sample is plotted it will tend to follow a normal dist provided n is large say at least $>= 30$.

But  using probability theory when we state CLT as:

Let $X_1, X_2,\ldots X_n$ is an iid random sample with mean mu and variance  sigma-square.
So the CLT is stated as $$ \frac{(\sum_iX_i)-n\mu}{\sigma \sqrt n}$$ tends to $N(0,1)$. 
So it is the cdf that tends to normal cdf and not pdf even if the original distribution is Non-normal

So, my question is how the concept of repeated samples, as defined for CLT, is implemented uaing random variable definition  of CLT?

My understanding is that $X_i$ represent the $i$-th observation among the n observations of a single random sample.

Or, is it that, Here, $n$ does not define number of observations in a single sample rather it denotes no. Of samples taken where each sample is of equal size and $X_i$ represent some measurable sample characteristic of each such sample, say sample mean?

Please clarify?

Comment: In the future please typeset in Mathjax. It makes it much easier to read. To see how I modified yours, click on my edit.

Comment: Anyone there to clarify? P.S. its urgent.

Comment: Apologies, we're using different words. $n$ is the thing that corresponds to $30$ in your example, i.e. the sample size.

Comment: Perhaps your confusion is that this notation doesn't leave room for $m$ the number of experiments done. For this you need to understand what random variables are. You can think of the variables $X_1,X_2\ldots X_n$ of representing the outcomes of one of the $m$ experiments. For instance if your sample size is $n=3$ you might have for the first experiment $(X_1,X_2,X_3) = (30.5,28.8,36.6)$ and then for the second experiment $(X_1,X_2,X_3) = (25.5,32.4,27.9)$ and then another for the third experiment, etc. The $X_i's$ are understood to be random, i.e. differ from experiment to experiment.

Comment: Then their sample mean is another random variable that varies from experiment to experiment, for experiment $m=1$ $\bar X = 32.0$ and for the second one $\bar X = 28.6,$ etc. Central limit theorem pertains to the distribution of $\bar X$... you could verify it by doing a bunch (say $m=100$) experiments and making a histogram. A lot of times only one experiment ($m=1$) is in front of us but still use what we know (or assume) about the distribution of the sample mean $\bar X$ to make inferences about the values of $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

Comment: So, bottomline, even though we say CLT is applicable for repeated sampling, but, as per mathematical definition of  CLT,  it is defined for a single sample with n obs. And sample mean is the mean of n realizations of n R.V.s. Sometimes we take one large sample of size n, i.e. n obs.,  from there we infer about population parameters.

Comment: clt is about the *distribution* of the sample mean. You know how the population has a distribution that you assume you're taking random draws from? Well when instead of taking one observation, take $n& randomly drawn and average them together. That's an observation of the sample mean,and we can look at it as being drawn from some population with a distribution as well. Clt says that distribution is approx normal with mean yada yada

Comment: The theory is understandable which is Zn = (Sn-nmu)/(sigma sq.root n) ~ N(0,1) where Sn =  X1+X2+...Xn. I need to relate the histogram visualization of sample means of m experiments with the mathematical formula of CLT. Here is my understanding. Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: The definition of n sample size i.e. # obs of a given sample and Not # of samples. X1, X2 ..Xn are r.v. corresponding to individual obs of a given sample. Now xbar = Sn/n for a given sample where Sn is as defined earlier. Now with this Sn, n, mu, sigma using CLT we approximate it to Z-scores. We then calculate the cdf for the particular z score i.e. area to the left of the z score. Now this has happened for only one experiment/trial/sample. So for m no. Of experiments or samples the above steps are repeated so we get a distribution of sample means of m no. Of samples representing normal curve

Answer (score 1):

The $X_i$ are random variables and each one $X_1,X_2,$ etc. represents the value of a particular observation. $n$ is the number of observations taken, as in $30$ in your example.

The CLT as you stated says that (under suitable conditions) $$ \sqrt{n}\frac{\bar X-\mu}{\sigma} \to_D N(0,1)$$ so that the sample mean's distribution begins to resemble the distribution of a $N(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$ as $n\to \infty.$

This says the exact same thing as you said colloquially before. If we did the experiment where we took $100$ observations a bunch of times and plotted a distribution of the resulting sample means then (provided $100$ is large enough for the particular application) it would look approximately normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2/n.$